# Does JpaPollingChannelAdapter have similar functionality to JdbcPollingChannelAdapter's UpdateSql?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a small Spring Boot application which uses Spring Integration to query an Oracle database for records of a certain status.

Initially I had a working POC using JdbcPollingChannelAdapter which also defined an update statement which changed the status of found records so they were not re-scanned.

The application uses Hibernate and thus I wanted to replace the Jdbc implementation with a JPA approach.

Thus I successfully implemented a JpaPollingChannelAdapter with a JpaExecutor to retrieve the results in entity form.

What I am trying to achieve is similar behavior to the Jdbc approach which would update all found records in the same transaction as the poller.

Is there a proper way to achieve this within the adapter or should I just use an entity dao within the message handler?

Hopefully that makes sense.

**Update**:

Looking [through the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jpa.html#jpa-outbound-channel-adapter) I'm assuming I'll need to use an OutboundChannelAdapter or Gateway (versus the InboundChannelAdapter since it's for retrieval only).

I guess my question then becomes how to properly wire that up, if I can do everything within a single handler, or if I need to define multiple channels, 1 to retrieve and the other to update the entity status.

Here is some basic code:

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private Reactor rootReactor;

    @Autowired
    private RunDao runDao;

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "notificationChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "60000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "-1"))
    public MessageSource<?> jpaMessageSource() {
        return new JpaPollingChannelAdapter(jpaSelectExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "notificationChannel")
    public void updateMessageStatus() {
        JpaOutboundGateway gateway = new JpaOutboundGateway(jpaUpdateExecutor());
        gateway.setGatewayType(OutboundGatewayType.UPDATING);
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaExecutor jpaSelectExecutor() {
        JpaExecutor executor = new JpaExecutor(this.entityManager);
        executor.setJpaQuery("select R from Run R where R.notificationStatus = 'NOT_SENT' and R.runStatus.status = 'COMPLETE' and R.runConfig.notificationRecipients is not null");
        executor.setEntityClass(Run.class);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaExecutor jpaUpdateExecutor() {
        JpaExecutor executor = new JpaExecutor(this.entityManager);
        executor.setJpaQuery("update Run R set R.notificationStatus = 'SENDING' where R.RunId = :RunId");
        executor.setEntityClass(Run.class);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "notificationChannel")
    public MessageHandler jpaMessageHandler() {
        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
                for (Run run : (ArrayList<Run>) message.getPayload()) {
                    rootReactor.notify("send-email-notification", Event.wrap(run));
                    //run.setNotificationStatus(Run.NotificationStatus.SENDING);
                    //runDao.merge(run);
                }
            }
        };

        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pollingAdapterFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(jpaMessageSource())
                .handle(jpaMessageHandler())
                .get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` functionality the `JpaExecutor` has `deleteAfterPoll` option.

You can override default `DELETE` with custom `UPDATE` using Hibernate `@SQLDelete` on the entity class.

Or yes, you can use `JpaOutboundGateway` in one-way more for `merge` operation in the same polling transaction. But in that case it must be `fixedDelay`, not `fixedRate` to not overlap tasks and don't poll the same data in the parallel thread.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I will investigate the JpaOutboundGateway merge approach using fixedDelay.

Comment: Just a follow-up question. I'm attempting to implement your second suggestion of using a JpaOutboundGateway. Should I replace the definition of the JpaPollingChannelAdapter in the code above with a JpaOutboundGateway adapter? I'm struggling with how to define both the select query to retrieve records, and the step to update the entity status.

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You use `JpaPollingChannelAdapter` for SELECT and `JpaOutboundGateway` for UPDATE. Is that clear ?

Comment: Okay I will keep both. Again sorry for all the questions. Should I define a second JpaExcutor for the JpaOutboundGateway? I'm confused on what additional channel/bean definitions I need to hookup everything in a single transaction. I will update the code above with my progress.

Comment: Would be better if you take a look to the Java DSL with the `Jpa` factory: https://spring.io/blog/2016/09/15/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-milestone-2-is-available

Comment: Thanks Artem, I'll look at the Java DSL approach as well (I added a stub above).
Perhaps I'm not understanding the flow. My best guess is to use InboundChannelAdapter -> Gateway (updating) -> ServiceActivator. I'm hoping the select and update are all performed within the same transactions.

Comment: I think ultimately I was overcomplicating the whole process. In the end I simply used Spring scheduler to pull and update records and send notifications. Thanks for the help Artem.